# Chaining Django models: how to format results on the template according to the specific model

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-template-filters

I have a view that allows me to work with two different models at once, thanks to itertools chain. I'm rendering the instances of the two chained models inside a table in my template, and I'd need the rows of the table to be formatted differently in case the instances are from one model as opposed to the other.

So basically: I'm chaining two models and displaying their instances in a table, and all the rows of the table that contain instances from model A should be formatted with a yellow background and all the rows containing instances from model B should have a blue background instead.

This is the view:

```
class BaseView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'base/base_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'base_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = Document.objects.order_by('due_date')
         return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['object_list'] = sorted(
             itertools.chain(Program.objects.all(), Document.objects.all()),
             key=attrgetter('validity_date'),
             reverse=True)
         return context
```

In logic, what I'd need in the template would be something like this:

```
if 
    object in object_list ***belongs*** to Program.objects.all() 

    (etc)

else 

    (etc)
```

The question is: how should I express that ***belongs***?

I've also looked into template tags but could not find the right way to go.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do your models have any unique identifying characteristics?

Comment: No, they mainly share the same attributes (name, description...).

Comment: Wait, they have only one completely different attribute, can I use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you should look for a way of identifying the model itself rather than checking if it is in a list. There is a built-in way of accessing the model name, but unfortunately that is inside the `_meta` attribute and you're not allowed to use attributes that start with underscores in a template.

So instead I would recommend simply adding one to your class definitions:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    model_name = 'Program'
    ...
```

Now you can just do:

```
{% if object.model_name == 'Program' %}
    ...
{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```